# Video Call in Ionic and Overlay Screen In Ionic Application

Tags: ionic4, mesibo

How can I integrate Mesibo Video APIs in Ionic? Gone through the docs but couldn't see anything IONIC specific.
Is there any IONIC Demo Application ?
Is there any other way to use Mesibo Android sdk in Ionic application?

I want to implement video call overlay screen concept where 'while one to one video call in place and user can work on all the application pages in parallel'. Please let know if this feature can be implemented in Ionic application using Mesibo APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mesibo provides native APIs for Android (Java & Kotlin), iOS (obj-c, Swift), C++, Javascript, and Python. You need to write a plugin if you like to using mesibo (or any native android library) from ionic

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try [cordova-call](https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/CordovaCall#onanswer), it works background and foreground quite well